# Can a multi-legged creature such as a Sleipnir wear multiple sets of magical horseshoes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Several magical horseshoes such as *[Horseshoes of Speed](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Horseshoes_of_Speed)* and *[Horseshoes of a Zephyr](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Horseshoes_of_a_Zephyr)* have the explicit requirement of the creature wearing all 4 shoes for the item take effect. However, some creatures like the Sleipnir from the Norse mythology have more than 4 legs, in this case exactly 8, which would allow him to wear two sets of horseshoes.

**Can a Sleipnir equipped with both sets of magical horseshoes benefit from both effects?**

While I do want to know about it for a Sleipnir, my question target multi-legged creatures in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

Both types of magical horseshoes are categorized by the Magic Item Compendium (pp. 260 and 274) as "tools," meaning they don't take up a body slot.  As long as you can get 'em on your hooves, you're good to go.

When I started this answer, I was expecting this trick to run afoul of another rule from the MIC (p. 219):

> As a default rule, treat creatures of any shape as having all the normal body slots available. Creatures never gain extra body slots for having extra body parts (for example, a marilith still has only one hands body slot and two rings body slots)

...but since the horseshoes don't take up any body slot at all, this rule doesn't apply.

Comment: if horse shoes do not fill a body slot, could an ordinary horse use both sets of horse shoes too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The requirements for the shoes to function explicitly states that all four shoes must be worn, not that the wearer must wear them on all (four) of its feet. The one restriction I see, and this isn't relevant to the Sleipnir, is that they are metal horseshoes not some other kind of footwear, so they would have to be affixed to horse-like hooves.